# Average distance from center to random point in rectangle

Tags: average

I need to find average squared distance from center in rectangle. One edge is 2, other one is 1.
On my understanding I need to find 
$$E[X^2+Y^2]$$
So I got $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}x^2+y^2dxdy$$
Is it ok, or I am missing something?

Comment: Assuming uniform distribution, the joint density is $\frac{1}{2}$ in the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're off by a factor of two because your $y$-range runs from -1 to 1 but you're computing an average.

To explain further, suppose that you're computing the average distance to the origin of a line segment $[-a,a]$ for $a>0$.  That should be

$$\frac{1}{2a} \int_{-a}^a |t| dt= \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a t dt = \frac{a}{2},$$

correct?

Well, you didn't divide by the size of the integration region (2 in your case).

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean?

Comment: I've edited my answer in response.